# Copy current item Edit Item info path form to create a new item in same list

Tags: infopath

I have a list whose Edit Item is configured by an Info Path form and customized to receive inputs using text box, drop down etc. After saving/submitting an approval workflow either Approves or Rejects the item. The requirement is to copy the entered details except the ID column to a new form when it is rejected. User would open the Rejected list and from that re-open the form and should give an button option to copy details to new item and create a new item, so that re-entering all the details can be avoided for the new list item.

Please recommend a technique or ways of accomplishing it.

Answer (score 0):

In list A, create a SP workflow (onitemchanged) that checks the approved status and creates a new item in the Rejected List.

In Rejected list, add a new field named "Approve again". Create a workflow that when that field is checked, it creates a new item in list A and calls the approval workflow (maybe).